# stack in recursive function

Tags: c#, recursion, stack, binary-tree

so I'm trying to write a function that will search a binary tree that contains stacks and will return a new stack that every cell of it contains the sum of the first three numbers of each stack in the given tree. I'm not sure if that makes sense, haha. anyways, what I was thinking of doing is building three function, one that builds a new stack, one that goes through the tree and calling another one that will do the calculation (the calculation one would essentially get a stack) but the problem is that every time it is being called a new stack would be created. any help? 
(sorry for any misunderstandings, English isn't my first language)

Comment: You will need to post your code.

Comment: Please provide the source code and see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example